# React Native + Firebase - Saving data in Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about storing data in the database.

I'm working on some screens within an app: the **login screen** (where the user can access your account), the **signup screen** (where the user can create a new account), the **screen where the user provides information** (such 'Mothers name and height'), and the **profile screen** (where information provided by the user is displayed).

My question is: how can I save this information provided by the user in Firebase Database?

I'm having no problems in **login screen** and **signup screen**, however I have no idea how I can save in Firebase Database the information provided by the user in the **screen where the user provides information**.

Can any of you guys help me with this? I know I can create a user with name, email and password using firebase auth, however I have no idea how I can save in Firebase Database the information provided by the user. And I know I can add a node but I don't know how. I read some articles but none of them talk about creating a node in Firebase.

Thanks in advance!

Notes:

*The **screen where the user provides information** comes after the user creates an account on the **signup scree**n.

*If you want to see what I'm trying to do, please look at the project in GitHub: https://github.com/JoaoVRodrigues01/React-Native-Codec-App

Comment: Why don't use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is in fact store all data in your firebase database. If you store only on local storage the user can delete it and lost all data that supposed to be available, or also can't share data between different users.

Remember that to write/read your database node, the user must have the correctly permissions, either be logged or your database allows anonymous access.

You can use `react-native-firebase` (https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/) if you need to persist your data, so use it locally when user is offline, for instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, do you think I should create a node or multiple nodes to save user data? I know the question may sound simple and stupid, but I'm just getting started with Firebase. I'm having difficulty saving the data provided by the user, as I said in the post. To be honest I do not have much idea how I can do this. I read some articles on the subject but could not get a clear enough answer. What I want to do is pretty simple for people who already work with the platform. Basically I want to store the data provided by the user in the database, such as the username and nickname.

Comment: It depends on what kind of data are you asking for the user. For example, if you need only name and email, you can use the default structure of user authentication (check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)

If you need more data like 'birth date, 'height', 'mothers name', for instance, then you can have only one node as 'user' to store all of this.

However, if you need more complex logic of relationship between more than 1 user, maybe creating 2 or 3 nodes will be needed.

I recommend you to look for noSQL database structures. Hope it helps